# Clojure - No matching method found

Tags: java, azure, clojure, azure-storage, clojure-java-interop

Can't figure out why clojure is telling me this function name can't be found. I'm trying to call the [setProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob._cloud_blob.setproperties?view=azure-java-stable) function on a [CloudBlockBlob, which inherits](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-java/blob/master/microsoft-azure-storage/src/com/microsoft/azure/storage/blob/CloudBlockBlob.java#L39) from [CloudBlob](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-java/blob/master/microsoft-azure-storage/src/com/microsoft/azure/storage/blob/CloudBlob.java).

```
(ns my-ns.infra.azure-blob
  (:import (com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob
             CloudBlob
             CloudBlockBlob
             CloudBlobClient
             CloudBlobContainer
             BlobContainerPublicAccessType
             BlobRequestOptions BlobProperties CloudBlob BlobContainerProperties)
           (com.microsoft.azure.storage
             CloudStorageAccount
             OperationContext
             )))

(def blob (-> "img-manip"
           get-container-cached
           (.getBlockBlobReference "some-file.txt")))


(def props (-> blob
           .getProperties))
```

How does clojure see the setProperties function? Via `clojure.reflect/reflect`--

```
#clojure.reflect.Method{:name setProperties,
                                    :return-type void,
                                    :declaring-class com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlob,
                                    :parameter-types [com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.BlobProperties],
                                    :exception-types [],
                                    :flags #{:final :protected}}
```

Is `blob` cast-able to CloudBlob? Yes:

```
(cast com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlob blob)
=>
#object[com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlockBlob
        0x7f613b97
        "com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlockBlob@7f613b97"]
```

Are my properties a `BlobProperties`? Yes:

```
(cast com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.BlobProperties props)
=>
#object[com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.BlobProperties
        0x55cd6938
        "com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.BlobProperties@55cd6938"]
```

What happens when i call .setProperties?

```
(.setProperties blob props)
     java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching method found: setProperties for class com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlockBlob
clojure.lang.Compiler$CompilerException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching method found: setProperties for class com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlockBlob, compiling:(/Users/micahsmith/printio/gooten-preview/gooten-preview-api/src/gooten_preview_api/infra/azure_blob.clj:72:1)
```

I don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setProperties` is a `protected` method:

```
protected final void setProperties(final BlobProperties properties) {
    this.properties = properties;
}
```

What you're doing would work if `setProperties` were a `public` method. You can reproduce this by defining similar classes in your Clojure project:

```
public abstract class Vehicle {
    public final void go(int miles) {
    }
}
public class MonsterTruck extends Vehicle { }
```

And in Clojure:

```
(def truck (MonsterTruck.))
(.go truck 1) ;; resolves base class method, works
```

But if you change `go` to `protected final void` you'll see the same error you're getting.